Jackson to parse bean<t> with list of T beans
To parse some webservice results I have a java bean that Jackson can parse like this:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(in, ResultPage.class);

Now inside my ResultPage, amongst other data I have a list of results (the payload I am after). Depending on the query that delivers the result, the type of listed documents can vary (Documents, Tags, Keywords, ...) but the general list format does not vary. Thus I made my ResultPage bean a generic type that contains a list of results like so:
public class ResultPage<T> {
    ...
    private List<T> results;
    ...
}

As a next step I'd have to call the parser while providing this type, and I am getting lost at
public <T> ResultPage<T> parseResultPage(InputStream in, Class<T> valueType) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(in, ResultPage<valueType>.class);
}

Also this (seemingly simpler attempt) does not compile for me:
ResultPage<Tag> rp = mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getContent(), ResultPage<Tag>.class);

How could I make such a setup work?

Meanwhile I found a good tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-deserialize-generic-type-with-jackson

The first link explains (with an equivalent Gson example) the Java reasons why this doesn't work (nor the currently accepted answer) and the second explains the workaround with a TypeReference.

Use TypeReference:
public <T> ResultPage<T> parseResultPage(String content, Class<T> resultType) throws IOException {
    TypeReference<ResultPage<T>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, typeRef);
}


What's the point of resultType here?
